# An IB Math HL question on normally distributed random variable.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Some Background:

Tim goes to a popular restaurant that does not take any reservations for tables. It has 
been determined that the waiting times for a table are normally distributed with a mean 
of 18 minutes and standard deviation of 4 minutes

The Question:

Tim has been waiting for 15 minutes. Find the probability that he will be seated 
within the next five minutes.

My Question:
Suppose $T$ is the random variable that represents the amount of time Tim spent at the restaurant, so $T \sim N(15, 4^2)$. The answer sheet says the above question can be answered by working out $P(T < 20 | T > 15)$. My question is why do you work it out that way instead of $P(15 < T <20 | T > 15)$

Comment: The easy way to do this on the calculator is to compute the cdf of $\frac{20-18}{4} = 1/2$ and substract the cdf of $\frac{15-18}{4} = -3/4$. Why? The answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is very simple $P(T < 20 | T > 15) = P(15 < T < 20 | T > 15)$